# Sql percentage on rows of a pseudo column

Tags: sql-server

I have this script below which shows my percentages for my pseudo column. I would like to get to introduce two more columns and get a collective figure for all records.

The problem is instead I just get one figure that duplicates on all records. What am I doing wrong?

**Initial script**

```
  SELECT ulIDSOrdProductionorTrading
    ,CASE 
        WHEN ulIDSOrdProductionorTrading IN ('Board Split', 'Production - Other')
            THEN 'Production'
        WHEN ulIDSOrdProductionorTrading = 'Trading'
            THEN 'Trading'
        END AS Unit
    ,Score
    ,count(*) * 100.0 / (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM dbo.Efficiency
        ) AS Percentage
FROM dbo.Efficiency
GROUP BY ulIDSOrdProductionorTrading
    ,Score
```

**after adding two columns**

```
    SELECT InvoiceDate
    ,ulIDSOrdProductionorTrading
    ,CASE 
        WHEN ulIDSOrdProductionorTrading IN ('Board Split', 'Production - Other')
            THEN 'Production'
        WHEN ulIDSOrdProductionorTrading = 'Trading'
            THEN 'Trading'
        END AS Unit
    ,Score
    ,COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
        FROM dbo.Efficiency
        ) AS Percentage
    ,ucINCInvNumber
    ,ucINCOrderNum
FROM dbo.Efficiency AS Efficiency_1
GROUP BY ulIDSOrdProductionorTrading
    ,Score
    ,InvoiceDate
    ,ucINCInvNumber
    ,ucINCOrderNum
```

Answer (score 0):

The query used at your pseudo-column is agnostic to your group of

```
ilIDSOrdProductionorTrading, Score, InvoiceDate, ucINCInvNumber, ucINCOrderNum
```

since you do not have a `where` or a `group by` and `having combo` in that query. You need to filter the query in the pseudo-column to make sure you have the right `count` for `Efficiency` for the given group. The only thing changing for the pseudo-column is the `count` of the group of the outer query which is divided by a constant.